# Mapping predictions of partially overlapping batches

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, nlp, pytorch

I'm working with pytorch_pretrained_bert for NER based on the implementation available here: https://github.com/kamalkraj/BERT-NER

When predicting on longer texts, the `predict` function in `bert.py` in there returns an out of index error. My current understanding is that this is due to the nr of bert tokens (which are not necessarily the same, and indeed in many cases are not the same as the number of tokens for ex. `nltk.word_tokenize()` returns) makes out of the input text. If this exceeds 512 (as this is the default length for the pre-trained models, if I understood correctly), it returns this error (and works fine for shorter input).
So, I decided to implement a wrapper that, in case I have more bert tokens (i.e. the stuff bert's own tokenizer returns) than 512, generates batches that partially overlap. The overlap is desired, because just cutting it up into pieces, padding the last one (as it is unlikely that my nr of tokens is divisible by 512, hence the last, shorter batch would require padding) loses context. It means, however, that I have to do predictions batch-wise, and then put things back together afterwards.

This cutting up into batches (of length 512) is straightforward enough. I'm currently working on the putting back together predictions part.
For this, I wrote the following code:

```
def map_batches(batches, blen):
    master = []
    for i in range(len(batches)-1):
        appendbatch = []
        # if first round, append first bit of current batch with only one prediction
        if i == 0:
            appendbatch = batches[0][:int(blen/2)-1]
        thisbatch = batches[i]
        nextbatch = batches[i+1]
        offset = int(blen/2)-1 # think -1 is needed for zero offsetting, but not sure, test/debug!
        for j in range(offset, blen-offset+2): # and debug +2 here too!
            thistuple = thisbatch[j]
            nexttuple = nextbatch[j-offset]
            if thistuple[1] > nexttuple[1]:
                thisbatch[j] = thistuple
            else:
                thisbatch[j] = nexttuple
        appendbatch.extend(thisbatch[int(blen/2)-1:])
        # and at end add last bit of last batch with only one prediction
        if i == len(batches)-2:
            appendbatch.extend(nextbatch[int(blen/2)+1:])
        master.append(appendbatch)
    return master

blen = 6
a = [('I-LOC', 0.1),
     ('O', 0.2),
     ('I-LOC', 0.5),
     ('O', 0.2),
     ('I-LOC', 0.9),
     ('O', 0.1)]

b = [('B-LOC', 0.6),
     ('O', 0.7),
     ('I-LOC', 0.8),
     ('O', 0.9),
     ('O', 0.99),
     ('O', 0.99)]
correct = [[('I-LOC', 0.1), ('O', 0.2), ('B-LOC', 0.6), ('O', 0.7), ('I-LOC', 0.9), ('O', 0.9), ('O', 0.99), ('O', 0.99)]]
batches = [a, b]
master = map_batches(batches, blen)
print('mapped: ', master)
print('correct:', correct)
```

The function `map_batches` should do the trick. The input lists overlap only partially; for the first 2 items in list `a`, I have only one prediction (that of a itself). Then for the next 6 tokens, I have two predictions, corresponding to `a[2:]` and `b[:6]`. And for the last 2, I have only b again. The function is supposed to put this together, based on which has the highest likelihood (made up numbers here, in the real code these are of course confidence scores of the label).

Checking this for my toy examples a and b, it works, i.e. the output of the above is:

> mapped:  [[('I-LOC', 0.1), ('O', 0.2), ('B-LOC', 0.6), ('O', 0.7), ('I-LOC', 0.9), ('O', 0.9), ('O', 0.99), ('O', 0.99)]]
>
> correct: [[('I-LOC', 0.1), ('O', 0.2), ('B-LOC', 0.6), ('O', 0.7), ('I-LOC', 0.9), ('O', 0.9), ('O', 0.99), ('O', 0.99)]]

Sorry for the long intro.

Now here's the question(s):

First of all, this is put together rather quickly. While it works for my toy example, I'm a bit anxious that it may not be correct (hence the comments for debugging/testing) for all cases (different batch sizes, etc.), and I plan to debug it more, obviously. Still, any thought or input on this problem would be much welcomed!

Second, and I guess the real question: this is a problem that I suspect must have been solved by someone long before already (and probably in a much better and more efficient way). Would anyone know any implementations for this in keras, tensorflow, numpy, sklearn or any of the other usual suspects?